# ASP MVC check value from DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

How can I check the selected value of a dropdownlistfor and use that value?

This is my dropdownlistfor:

```
@Html.Label("Kies wanneer:") @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOption, Model.LstDays)
```

When the selected value is "morgen" I need to do something. But I have no idea how to check this.

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.DropDownListFor` is just a helper method, which you are using in your view to generate HTML markup. When you open the final result in the browser, it will be a `<select>` tag with some `<option>` tags inside. When the user interacts with your DropDown, one of the option tags will be marked as selected in the HTML, but there will be no request to the server and your C# code will not know about this.

Depending on your requirements, you may submit the value to the server immediately after the user changes the selector, or once the whole form is submitted together with the rest of the page. You can do this using AJAX requests. You can write JavaScript, which reads the selected options from the `<select>` tag and passes them in the request data.

You question is too specific and you need to understand the whole picture of how client-server application work, specifically ASP.NET MVC.